# firebase messaging and flutter sdk driver version solving failed

Tags: flutter

Details about issue :        Because every version of flutter_driver from sdk depends on process 4.0.0-nullsafety.2 which depends on platform ^3.0.0-nullsafety.1, every version of flutter_driver from sdk requires platform ^3.0.0-nullsafety.1.
And because firebase_messaging >=0.2.0 <7.0.2 depends on platform ^2.0.0, flutter_driver from sdk is incompatible with firebase_messaging >=0.2.0 <7.0.2.
So, because receiptree depends on both firebase_messaging ^6.0.13 and flutter_driver any from sdk, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in working...
pub get failed (1; So, because xxxx depends on both firebase_messaging ^6.0.13 and flutter_driver any from sdk, version solving failed.)

Please help me to format below code

```
version: 0.9.9-beta+9
```

environment:
sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
depedencies:

## Auth

firebase_auth: ^0.15.5+3
google_sign_in: ^4.4.0
flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
apple_sign_in: ^0.1.0

## Notification

firebase_messaging: ^6.0.13
firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.5.0+11
fluttertoast: ^4.0.1

## Core

provider: ^4.0.4
auto_route: ^0.4.2
flutter_mobx: ^1.1.0
mobx: ^1.1.1
mobx_codegen: ^1.0.3
firebase_ml_vision: ^0.9.3+8

## Dependency injection

inject:
git:
url: https://github.com/google/inject.dart.git
path: package/inject
ref: 7c3cbf6

## Storage

shared_preferences: ^0.5.6+3
firebase_storage: ^3.1.5
cloud_firestore: ^0.13.4+2

## UI

photo_view: ^0.9.2
flutter_page_indicator: 0.0.3
datetime_picker_formfield: ^1.0.0
image_picker: ^0.6.4
flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.4.0
image_cropper: ^1.2.1
flutter_typeahead: ^1.8.0
flutter_masked_text: ^0.8.0
video_player: null

## Utility

flutter_svg: ^0.18.1
flutter_image_compress: ^0.6.5+1
firebase_analytics: ^5.0.11
firebase_crashlytics: ^0.1.3+3
package_info: ^0.4.0+16
http: ^0.12.2
dartz: ^0.9.1
faker: ^1.2.1
intl: ^0.16.1
printing: ^3.6.0
image_gallery_saver: ^1.5.0
dio: ^3.0.10
flutter_email_sender: ^3.0.1

## Unknown

path_provider: ^1.6.5
flutter:
sdk: flutter

## The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.

## Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.

cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
random_string: ^2.1.0
permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1
share: ^0.6.5+2
url_launcher: ^5.7.1

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter
mockito: ^4.1.1
flutter_driver:
sdk: flutter
test: any
timeago: ^2.0.26
flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.0
auto_route_generator: ^0.4.0
build_runner: null
inject_generator:
git:
url: https://github.com/google/inject.dart.git
path: package/inject_generator
ref: 7c3cbf6

Comment: sorry for format

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem. The problem is coming from firebase messaging.
Currently, you have:

```
firebase_messaging: ^6.0.13
```

which limits firebase messaging to a version 6.
Replace it with

```
firebase_messaging: ^7.0.0
```

And it should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

try to upgrade you flutter packages

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

Then update the major version using this command

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

If you want to do it manually then check which version is outdated

```
flutter pub outdated
```